# Why are my render times 30+ minutes, but other people's are ~3 minutes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am currently using Sheep It! to render my blend (built on v2.68c) on multiple computers, and I noticed something rather strange. According to the log on-site, the frames rendered from other people's blends were completing in 3 to 4 minutes. This was on an 4 core i5. My main rig (with an 8 core i7) was completing frames in no less than half an hour. How is this possible?

To clarify, these people's frames are very complex, often with very detailed textures. I have 2 objects in my blend. Below are the options I changed for my blend:

- Aspect Ratio: 1000px x 1000px
- Output: PNG
- Clamp Indirect: 0.98
- Render Sampling: 128
- Min Light Bounces: 0
- Max Light Bounces: 4
- Cycles Render

Is there something in there that I should change to make it go faster? I can't really comprehend how it's going to quickly.

EDIT: To answer what @Duarte asked...

- System Specs: i7-920, 3GB DDR3, GT 630, Windows 10
- I have two circles, extended to form a sort of coin with a star on it. It is not complex at all.
- I have Firefox and Steam running in the background, but not actively. I've been away from the computer for 8 hours and noticed this behavior. (I am running Blender from Steam.)
- I made sure when I began rendering that the blend was set for CPU rendering.
- [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hLkJ.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

And to answer what @pycoder asked, yes, I am using Cycles Render.

Comment: So you changed from Blender Render to Cycles Render?

Comment: What are your system specs? How is your scene setup? What objects do you have? Could you post some screenshots? What are your computer specs? What processor do you have, under which operating system? Are you comparing CPU vs GPU rendering by mistake? What other application are running in the backgroud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have *Square Samples* ticked under your *Sampling* render settings. It squares whatever sample value you have setup.

You have 128 samples specified so `128^2 = 16384` so you are basically attempting to render with 16384 samples which is **a lot**.

[image]

Comment: I thought that was for making the render tiles square... thank you, friend

Comment: That would be named something like "Square Buckets" or "Square Tiles". Anyway you can control tile sizes from the *Performance>Tiles* settings; they are already square @16x16 pixels size.

Comment: Yes, I saw a post about optimal tile sizes for CPU rendering that said 16px was the best size for 8 cores. I never thought to look back at the sampling. What really confused me was that the realtime rendering took place so quickly, and it couldn't have taken _that_ much more time to sample 4x more.