# Slow Blender render of simple scene on fast computer

Tags: rendering

Blender is taking several minutes to render a simple plane and torus.
Here are my computer specs.

Blender 2.79b

DELL XPS 8930 Base
• Intel Core i7 Processor Label
• NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GTX 1080 with 8GB GDDR5X Graphics Memory
• 32-inch (1280 x 768)
• 8GB DDR3 System Memory (2 Dimm)
• 512GB PCIe x4 SSD + 1TB 7200RPM HDD
• 64GB,, DDR4, 2666MHz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my render times 30+ minutes, but other people's are ~3 minutes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76149/why-are-my-render-times-30-minutes-but-other-peoples-are-3-minutes)

Comment: Start with; Reboot, update/reinstall graphics drivers. Then make sure nothing else is using the CPU/GPU/Memory. In Blender load factory settings and test the default scene. You can also download and run the standalone version of Blender from the Additional Downloads link. We look forward to hearing how it goes.