# Optimizing Crystal Render Times in Cycles: Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, optimization

I don't know if i get an answer here but I have an optimization question. 
I made a crystal in blender (star wars kyber crystal). The way i did it is 3 parts.  A small crystal on the inside that has a ton of spec and reflectivity so the color can come through. A translucent semi transparent outside krystal with slight scratch displacement on the outside of that. And then another bigger and rougher crystal with stronger displacement on the outside of that but covering only half. 
I am using cycles and the renders take up to 8 minutes per frame. This is only 1 object rendering in 25560x1440 resolution. Is a rendertime like this normal? I am seeing full scenes with houses and grass in blender that take 5 minutes.

What should I be optimizing in order to get a faster render but also have a clear render without noise?

I am having a 1080Ti card with 32gb of ram

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76149/why-are-my-render-times-30-minutes-but-other-peoples-are-3-minutes/76151#76151

Comment: There is no  stardard or non standartd rendering time. It all has to do with the complexity of the scene, the render settings and the real computing power of your machine. 25560*1440 is a very large image... unless you have a computer with several multicore processors and more than one GPU, you can expect your render times to be long. But it is hard to help you if you don't share information on the amount of vertices, settings for subsurf modifiers, the settings for particles, volumetrics, number of samples, etc, etc. No one in this site has a crystal ball to look into and see your project...

Comment: i will be sharing my scene here as soon as i go home. Just posted it for now so i wont forget later:)